# CSV reader and random sample

Tags: python, csv

I was trying to make a CSV reader function which I can't seem to work and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
fileobj = open("...") # open file for reading as usual
reader = csv.reader(fileobj)
for row in reader:
    # process the row
    first_column = row[0]     
    second_column = row[1]
    third_column = row[2]
fileobj.close()

print(random.sample(first_column, 2))
```

I understand that first_column is only giving me the bottom value of that column and therefore not allowing me to print a random sample. I'm not sure how to fix this.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a typical transpositioning pattern `zip(*...)`:

```
with open("...") as fileobj: # open file with context manager as recommended ;)
    reader = csv.reader(fileobj)
    rows = list(reader)  # if you need the rows as well
    columns = list(zip(*rows)) # you can just use the fresh reader here as well
    # columns = zip(*rows)  # suffices in Python2
print(random.sample(columns[0], 2))
```

See the docs on [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: I get a TypeError: 'zip' not subscriptable when trying this not sure what that means

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly now!